# Error null! from Volley on Http Post Request with JSon object

Tags: android, http, post, null, android-volley

I'm getting a Null Exception with JSon object from Volley

I filled the JSon object before it is used, and not in the parameterlist.

```
public static void SendPost6(final Context context){
    final String TAG= "-->Error-->";
    String url = "http://192.168.44.120/test_php_neuer_user.php";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject paramsObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        paramsObject.put("name", "Name");
        paramsObject.put("email", "EMail");
        userObject.put("user",paramsObject);
    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        Toast.makeText(context, "JSON-Error:" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            userObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Volley Response:" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }},

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //handle errors#
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed with error msg:\t" + error.getMessage());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error StackTrace: \t" + error.getStackTrace());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Volley Error:" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();

                    try {
                        byte[] htmlBodyBytes = error.networkResponse.data;
                        Log.e(TAG, new String(htmlBodyBytes), error);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

    queue.add(request);
    //AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

I want to add the json object request into the queue to perform http-post. Volley Error is "null"

Answer (score 0):

The firewall blocked the network access. This is why i'm getting response null. Solved.